# Firefox and Chrome Calculating image width different on load

Tags: jquery, firefox, parseint

I have a series of sections I loop through in order to calculate the widths of it's contents.  The sum of these widths are set to the width of the container so all the contents can fit. This is how it works:

```
$(window).load(function() {
   function sizePanels(){
       sunWidth = 0;
       var sections = $("section");

       sections.each(function(){

           var totalWidth = 0,
           select = $(this).find('.mainScroll div, .mainScroll img');

           select.each(function(index) {
                totalWidth += parseInt($(this).outerWidth(true), 10);
           });

           $(this).css({ 'width' : totalWidth});
       });
   }

   sizePanels();
});
```

In Chrome and Safari, this works great. In firefox, `totalwidth` is an entirely different numberBecause of this, the sections are not wide enough in firefox. This line isn't being calculated correctly:

```
totalWidth += parseInt($(this).outerWidth(true), 10);
```

Is there any reason why firefox would not calculate this correctly?

UPDATE: It looks like firefox calculates the width of all images 15px less than it should be. I ran a test where this dame function is run after page load and it works correctly. It seems that this is an image load issue, but it is still within a window.load function. Odd. If I comment out this one line, Firefox returns the correct widths:

```
$(this).css({ 'width' : totalWidth});
```

But I need this line to set the correct container width!

Comment: NOTE: It seems to be calculating the first section's width correctly, but not the second, third, fourth, etc

Comment: So, you think this is a problem of `parseInt` and not `.outerWidth`? Browsers layout pages slightly differently so I would assume that `.outerWidth` returns different values in different browsers.

Comment: Looks like images are not fully loaded at time you calculate outerWidth. You should set image attributes height & width or using onload handler to check when images are loaded. You could test it using window onload handler if actually images size which make it buggy: `$(window).on('load',sizePanels);`. Forget my comment if you use your sizePanels method after all images are loaded.

Comment: @Felix - yes you could be right, but its all relative. If firefox is calculating it differently, everything still should fit.

Comment: @roasted - the entire function is placed within a $(window).load function. THe images are sized via css (smaller or larger than the actual size of the image) so I do not believe that would fix it

Comment: It is definitely an image related issue - If I set the width and height in the <img> tag and remove the css, height: 100%; width: auto....it works. But I need that css. any idea how to work around this?